# Grub rescue please help

Tags: grub2

Like a dummy I deleted the Ubuntu partition on my hdd and restarted my computer. Now when it boots up I get

```
Error: no such partition
Grub rescue>
```

I don't have a asus repair disk nor a Ubuntu disk
I'm using my iPhone as I don't have anything else. Am I screwed or is there a fix?

Comment: Don't worry. You should put a LiveCD and type a little code and it will be solved.

Comment: Don't have a live cd. :/

Comment: Ok, you don't have any kind of CD.. You must download one, I recommend the LiveCd from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: I have no way to download it as this is he onl computer I have, I'm using my iPhone to get on here.

Comment: After that there is not so much that we can do. You don't have CD, you don't have Internet.. Do you have computer?

Comment: So what do you want to do? Would you like to recover the deleted partition? Reinstall Ubuntu? If you need to recover the deleted partition, you can try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). If you need to reinstall Ubuntu, you have to download the Ubuntu ISO installer and burn it to a CD or create a LiveUSB and boot into it.

Comment: Do you want to install Ubuntu again? If yes, then it is off-topic. But if you don't want, it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @AnwarShah I don't agree that it is off-topic in either case. If he got in trouble because he tried Ubuntu we should lend him a hand in  recovering if we can.

Comment: To be clear: you *can* recover, but you will need a live CD.

Answer (score 1):

i think it was a dual boot, if it was win 7,  you will have to borrow a windows installation disk and boot from it, 
then you have to go to the repair option and then the command prompt,  there u will have to type "bootrec.exe"

it will fix your boot sector and thus, it will enable to boot win 7.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Comment: I don't have a disk but I'll see if I can borrow one from a friend, thanks

Comment: I think this is your best bet. Your disk has not been blanked. If you never removed your Windows partition it should still be there and you should be able to use it. Your Ubuntu stuff is probably still on the disk but it won't be able to be found because you removed the partition information. Ubuntu LUGs or other computer clubs or computer shops should be able to loan you a bootable CD or flash drive to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. get a rescue disk (eg [Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair)), or download it from another computer
2. boot the broken computer on this disk
3. repair it

Answer (score -3):

You're pretty boned. Right now, you just have an (almost) empty hard drive or partition.

Since it's pretty much blank, reinstalling shouldn't be too tough.

So, I recommend to re-install Ubuntu using Ubuntu Live CD or creating a Ubuntu USB disk. Of course, you should select the same old partition from which your Ubuntu get deleted. This will restore (reinstall) Ubuntu and at the same time, You Windows system will be again bootable (Because, at the final stage of Ubuntu installation, it will look for other OSs in the disk)

Comment: It's going to suck as I don't have a win7 os disk or any other os disk

Comment: The disk isn't really blank. You should be able to recover from this. Once you can reboot you can use Windows to download and create a rescue CD or Ubuntu CD.